# Vuejs root and component structure

Tags: vue.js

In the [documents](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#creating-an-application-instance), the root element is created as follows:

```
const RootComponent = {
  /* options */
}
const app = Vue.createApp(RootComponent)
const vm = app.mount('#app')
```

However, soon I realized createApp() can be left blank:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({})
app.component('component-a', {
  /* ... */
})
app.mount('#app')
```

In the second example, what is the root element? A default one?

A side question, I understand it is better to use props and $emit to pass data around, but is there any way to directly access a component through its $data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root Component is always `app` instance.

`RootComponent` variabile contains global options (property) for `app` Component. ([Component Instance Properties](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#component-instance-properties))

About the side question, You should consider if the component handle application data (shared between different component inside your page) or local data between the component and it's parent.

In the first case is better to use a State Management Library as [Vuex](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html), otherwise you should use `$emit` to change parent data passed via props to the child component.